# How can I customize the Apache licence for my template design?

Tags: html, css, website-design, legal, licenses

I have a template with the following license:

```
/*! 
* name of original creator - name of theme (originalcreator.com)
* Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0. 
* For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. */
/* Global Styles */
```

I've modified about 50% of the CSS and 70% of the HTML, just same as I've just copied some code for my project, but actually I've made many modifications with many deletions and additions. I want to give it to my client, but what can I do?

- Can I delete that CSS comment?
- How can I get a license for my modifications?
- Can I write "designed by me" in the footer?

Comment: I have done the same thing lately. Only 1/3rd of the original code exists and I wondered the same thing. I decided to modify the tag in the footer (or license in your case) to something like "Based upon theme x by yz with many modifications by me." That way your bases are covered. BTW- I like this question!!

Answer (score 2):

> Can I delete that CSS comment?

No, it's not just a *comment*, it's a license and attribution notice for the original creator.

Even though you modified the original code, as I covered in my answer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57362/is-it-legal-and-ethical-to-remove-license-notices-from-third-party-code/57364#57364), under [Licensing conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License#Licensing_conditions), the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) states: `You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices from the Source form of the Work...`

> How can I get a license for my modifications?

Simply add a license and attribution notice like the one in your question (with your name as the "creator") to any modifications or derivative works that you wish to assign a license to. You may even add different license terms and conditions as stated [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0):

> You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may
>   provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use,
>   reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such
>   Derivative Works as a whole...

`Can I write "designed by me" in the footer?`

As long as you maintain the license attributions and copyright notices in the code, you're free to add any *generalized* visible statements like this to your template, which many template and theme designers using third-party libraries & frameworks chose to do.